# Found code to update user role but doesn't display [HttpGet] method or ViewPage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I've found some code which claims to be a successful way of updating a Users role. However the solution just displays code for the [HttpPost] method. As I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, I'm not sure what would go in my [HttpGet] method or my ViewPage.

Just wondering if anyone could look at the code and perhaps give some suggestions or give me a completely new direction.

I'll show the code I have at the moment, as the roles do not update when I change the role attached to my User.

Thanks!

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ManageUserRoles()
        {
            var roleList = _context.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr =>
                new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Roles = roleList;

            var userList = _context.Users.OrderBy(u => u.UserName).ToList().Select(uu =>
                new SelectListItem { Value = uu.UserName.ToString(), Text = uu.UserName }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Users = userList;
            return View();

        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ManageUserRoles(string UserName, string RoleName)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = _context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName,
                StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

            var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_context));

            var roleList = _context.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList()
            .Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Roles = roleList;

            var userList = _context.Users
            .OrderBy(u => u.UserName).ToList()
            .Select(uu => new SelectListItem { Value = uu.UserName.ToString(), Text = uu.UserName }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Users = userList;
            return View("ManageUserRoles");
```

**MANAGEUSERROLES VIEW**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetAllUsers", "UserAdmin"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <p>
        UserName: @Html.DropDownList("UserName",
            (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Users, "Select...")
        Role Name: @Html.DropDownList("RoleName",
            (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Roles, "Select...")
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

**CODE FOUND FROM OTHER STACKOVERFLOW POST**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual ActionResult ManageUser(ApplicationUser user, string role)
    {
        if  (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var oldUser = _userManager.FindById(user.Id);
            var oldRoleId = oldUser.Roles.SingleOrDefault().RoleId;
            var oldRoleName = _context.Roles.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == oldRoleId).Name;

            if (oldRoleName != role)
            {
                _userManager.RemoveFromRole(user.Id, oldRoleName);
                _userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, role);

            }
            _context.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

            return RedirectToAction("GetAllApplicationUsers", "UserAdmin");
        }

        return View(user);

    }
```

Comment: You want to create a view to display the user? Seems like a basic MVC tutorial would cover how to return a view result from an action method. What have you researched? What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to display a User and the User Role  the User is associated with. Then I want to update the UserRole from a dropdown selection. I've posted the code I have in the question now. At the moment, when changing the user role, it does not update the database.

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, an HTTP GET operation usually just gets something. A POST is used to pass data back to the server via the request body, a PUT or PATCH updates otherwise existing data and a DELETE deletes data.

You indicate that you don't know what would go in your GET operation. What is it you want to get?

Typically, in a GET operation, you'd pass in either an identifier of a specific entity to retrieve or exclude any parameters in favor of listing everything.

It's unclear what you're seeking to do specifically, but if you're looking to get, say, the role itself, you might have:

```
[HttpGet("role/{roleId}")]
public virtual IActionResult GetRole(int roleId) //Can't tell from your code what type Id uses
{
  var role = DB.Roles.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == roleId);
  return Ok(role);
}
```

Of course, you'd likely want to map this result to some sort of other class since your caller may not need all the information you're storing in the database.

You mention giving suggestions on the code - is there something wrong with it that it needs changing? Are you just looking for optimizations?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What I have in the view at the moment is a dropdown selectlist of my Users and a selectlist of my Roles. When I change the role on my user, it doesn't save to the database. Therefore, I was seeking other ways of doing it. At the moment my views are not strongly typed. I will post my logic I have at the moment above.

Comment: Your post suggests that you're pulling a lot of ideas off StackOverflow, but the logic itself and your intent suggest that you don't actually understand what's happening in the code you're placing.  Your original POST method does not save any data, it's only reading from your context. Your second POST method might be saving data, but uses a repository class you provide no code for, so who knows what it's doing. Forget other SO posts - what of this is your code and what isn't doing as it should?